# How to send content of a file in a tSendMail

Tags: java, email, talend

i try since some days to send one mail with different informations from child job and father job.

see my jobs below:

[image: in the father job, it loads a cfg file by store. it loads my context variables]
[image: depending the date and other information from cfg file, it launch a child job]
[image: last part of father job]

and my tRunJob_3
[image: tRunJob_3]

at the end of this job, i can put informations from tAggregateRow in the email, but it send several email (one mail by condition "if" approved `DeinitJob --- if --- tRunJob_3`)

my file generated by tFileOutputDelimited_1 in the father job contains all the information i need to put in the final mail.

1: how to display these informations in one email (no attachement) ?

2: i have this error in my console:

```
For input string: "7.91'7.91"
multiple points
```

what it means ?

---

EDIT:

with the modification below, it send me 1 email with the informations collected
[image]

in my `tjavaflex`:

code initial

```
// start part of your Java code
      boolean loop ;
      System.out.println("## START\n#");
```

code principal

```
// here is the main part of the component,
// a piece of code executed in the row
// loop
// code sample:
System.out.println("## LOAD...\n#");
if ((String)globalMap.get("message") != null) {
globalMap.put("message", (String)globalMap.get("message") + row5.mag + " qt: " + row5.qt + " p1: " + row5.p1 + "\n" ) ;
}
```

code final:

```
// end of the component, outside/closing the loop
loop = true ;
System.out.println("## END\n#");
```

with a `if loop` between `tjava` and `tsendmail`

but still have my error:

```
For input string: "7.91'7.91"
multiple points
```

Comment: How big can the size of this final text string be? can you append the file data to a string using globalMap.put("emailtext", string_from_file) and then use this (String)globalMap.get("emailtext") as email body?

Comment: i already tried but the problem is i don't know how to successively put information line by line from the `tfileinputdelimited` in the globalmap

Comment: tfileinputdelimited will give row by row output and you can read in tJavaRow and keep appending it.   tFileInputDelimited-->tJavaRow and in tJavaRow put your code as globalMap.put("yourstringvar", (String)globalMap.get("yourstringvar")+input_row.schemacolumnname of tJavaRow..

Comment: ok thanks. but it send several emails. i link the tjavarow to tsendmail with a row (main)

Comment: no you have to use onComponentOk or onSubJobOk